# java glassfish jdk 7 jre 6 version conflict

Tags: conflict, java, versions

Downloaded JDK 7 from Oracle Java (comes w Glassfish) and installed on a Windows 7 machine.
In the shell, when I issue these commands:

javac -version
java -version

... I get two different versions.  The compiler seems to be Java 7 but the JRE appears to be Java 6. Obviously this is a problem because programs compiled in Java 7 throw exceptions when run in Java 6 JRE.

Question 1: why does a JDK have different versions for the javac.exe compiler and the java.exe?

Question 2: how is it expected to be setup to work?

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: why does a JDK have different versions for the javac.exe compiler and the java.exe?

It doesn't. You already have a Java 6 JRE installed and this is in your `PATH` before the JDK 7's `bin` directory. Remove the JRE 6 `bin` directory from your `PATH`.

> Question 2: how is it expected to be setup to work?

Make sure the `bin` directory of your Java 7 JDK is in the `PATH` and not the Java 6 JRE `bin` directory.

See the [JDK Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html), especially the part [Updating the PATH Environment Variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check you JAVA_HOME environment variable and make sure it points to the correct JDK, then check the 'path' environment variable and make sure you don't have duplicate jre/jdk paths there.